# Currency Symbol after making making Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift

While working on a project My task is to covert the currency into Niria and I successfully convert them into Niria but the problem occurs when I have to show it as attributed, 
When I Convert the simple string to the attributed One strik through is missing from the symbol

```
let balance = "₦ 450.00"
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: balance, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 48)])
        if balance.contains(".") {
            myMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)], range: NSRange(location: balance.length - 2, length: 2))
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the new San Francisco font.

A workaround would be to use Helvetica

```
let balance = "₦ 450.00"
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: balance, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 48.0)!])
if balance.containsString(".") {
    myMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0)!], range: NSRange(location: balance.characters.count - 2, length: 2))
}
```

Note: Unfortunately, I haven't migrated to Swift 3. I am still using Swift 2.2

**Edit : In Swift 3.0**

```
let balance = "₦ 450.00"
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: balance, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 48.0)!])
if balance.contains("."){
    myMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 22.0)!], range: NSRange(location: balance.characters.count - 2, length: 2))
}
```

Comment: You are right this is the problem with the system fonts hope fully apple will do something regarding this